# Google Tag Manager (GTM) Error. Primary Expression Expected

Tags: javascript, html, object, tawk.to

I keep getting this error: Error at line 5, character 2: Parse error. primary expression expected

This is what the custom HTML looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//paste your Tawk embed code here, without Script tags

<script type="text/javascript">
var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
(function(){
var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
s1.async=true;
s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/5a2863145d3202175d9b6c41/default';
s1.charset='UTF-8';
s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');
s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
})();
</script>
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You seem to have a double script tag open. Could you clarify or post a bit more of your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You have a second `<script>` tag inside your original code, which is invalid. It should look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //paste your Tawk embed code here, without Script tags

    var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
    (function(){
    var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    s1.async=true;
    s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/5a2863145d3202175d9b6c41/default';
    s1.charset='UTF-8';
    s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');
    s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
    })();

</script>
```